# Javascript array destruct to different variables with getting namespaces

Tags: javascript

```
const arr = [{
  name: 'some1',
  state: false,

},
{
  name: 'some2',
  state: true,
}];
```

I need to pass the data to API with different vars. Dynamic something like this. But this doesn't work.

```
let [arr.map(res => res.name)] = arr.map(res => res.state)
// ERROR: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target
// Expect for
// let some1 = false
// let some2 = true
```

Comment: Please elaborate the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `reduce` operation, not a `map` one.

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'some1',
  state: false,

},
{
  name: 'some2',
  state: true,
}]

const result = arr.reduce( (acc, i) => ({...acc, [i.name]:i.state}), {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's good to note though that for the general case, you can do something like
`arr.reduce( (acc, i) => {acc[i.name] = i.state; return acc;})` so you don't create a new object each iteration. It makes a difference only if you have a relatively big array, but I think it's still noteworthy

Comment: @RonB. indeed. This way is wasteful for a big array, it's just shorter and for small arrays you'll never notice the difference. If the OP had an array of hundreds of items I would never write it like this

Comment: Yes, works, thank you. But the Websorm underlined the next
console.log(result.some1);
// TS2339: Property 'some1' does not exist on type '{}'.
And I use Typescipt, yes

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.forEach()` you can iterate each element.

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'some1',
  state: false,

},
{
  name: 'some2',
  state: true,
}];

const result = {};
arr.forEach((ele) => {
  result[ele.name] = ele.state;
});
console.log(result);
```